# Travelling to Kuwait by Road

Tags: visas, gcc

My profession is Worker Supervisor, resident of Saudi Arabia and am also qualified graduate in law, in addition to some other qualifications. Will I get a Visa on Arrival at Kuwaiti land border?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Answer (score 2):

Kuwait has implemented a new e-visa system; which you must use in lieu of on-arrival visas.

The system is available [at this link](https://evisa.moi.gov.kw/evisa/home_e.do).

On that same page, it lists the valid professions which are eligible for the system.  Your profession is not listed and extra qualifications do not matter as it is the profession listed on your residency which is taken into consideration.